# Where to place interfaces when using MVVM

Tags: design-patterns, mvvm

### EDIT:

I where provided several interfaces that describe all the functionality that the project should contain. I don't know how to organize the project thow. this are my options I don't know which one will be the most appropiate:

1. Create a new project referencing the one that contains the interfaces. Start implementing the interfaces in that project.
2. Place the implementation next to each interface in the project. In other words if the interface IFoo.cs is in the folder Model then place Foo.cs in the same folder.
3. Place all interfaces in a folder called interfaces.

### Edit 2

I basically where provided with something like:

[image]

the interfaces are not organized they are all in the same namespace and directory. I have to organize that and implement it using the mvvm pattern.

Comment: What are the interfaces about?

Comment: How the entire project ought to work. I was thinking to create a new project (class library) where that project implements all the interfaces using the mvvm pattern. That way in one project I will have the interface and in the other project I will have the implementation.

Comment: Why are you using the interfaces? Are you using Dependency Injection? If you know the purpose of the interfaces then you will be able to put them in the correct place.

Comment: It's still a good idea to place all commonly used classes and interfaces in an Infrastructure project.

Comment: Your additions to the question do not explain why you need the interfaces. If you want other programmers to implement the interfaces in other projects/solutions, you should move the interfaces to separate projects. An then you would still have to think about what interfases should be clustered.

Comment: The interfaces are not really needed in my point of view. They where provided to me so that I know what to work on and to have a picture of how the application will work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where you want to access/implement the interface.

a) If you want the interface to be at presentation tier then go-ahead and create a project called Common and place all your interface which you assumed to be use across multiple project.

b) If you want the interface to be visible on multiple tier such as Service contracts in WCF which should be available in both presentation tier and middle/service tier. Then you can put them in a Shared projects which will be shared among multiple tiers.